# Accessibilty for WCAG Standards - How to handle a label within a label

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag

I'm trying to figure out how to mark up some code using WCAG standards, but it's a little complicated when I run into this situation:

```
<div class="form-group">

    <label>Entry Method</label>

    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" /> Upload file
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" /> Enter Manually
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" /> Load Template
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

What do I do with the first "label"? How do I use "for" and "id" in this scenario?

Answer (score 7):

A `label` accompanies a single form field, rather than a group of fields. Grouping form fields is achieved using a `fieldset` instead of a `div`, which is accompanied by a `legend` instead of a `label`:

```
<fieldset class="form-group">

    <legend>Entry Method</legend>

    <div>
        <label>
            <input type="radio" /> Upload file
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" /> Enter Manually
        </label>

        <label>
            <input type="radio" /> Load Template
        </label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

See [H71 of WCAG 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H71.html) for a detailed write-up.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but <legend> is used elsewhere with different css attached to it that can't apply to this. Is there another appropriate tag?

Comment: No, I'm afraid there isn't. You'll have to see if you can override those styles somehow.